# What is the connection between climate change and phosphorus and positive feedback loop?

Tags: climate-change, environmental-protection

So what is the connection between climate change and phosphorus and what are some examples of potential feedback loops of this connection.

I think a very common response is probably the leakage of some of the applied phosphorus (in fertilizer application) into rivers/ocean etc.

Comment: So what have you found/what makes you think there may be?  I know nothing on the subject, but it seems a rather random question without some kind of background :-)  You mention agricultural leakage, but not any reasoning beyond that.